min-width vs flex-basis is there any difference?
What is the difference between min-width and flex-basis, other than the fact that flex-basis only works on flex items?
Flex is a new concept for me. I have been watching some YouTube videos, but they oversimplify everything. One of them mentioned that flex-basis and min-width do the same thing, except that flex-basis only works on flex items. Thanks for your answers.

both are have a difference
basically min- width apply the element's width does not go below the specified value even if the content is smaller or the container is resized
use like that
.element {min-width: 200px;}

in other hand flex-basis
basically it the initial main size of a flex item before any free space is distributed according to the flex-grow and flex-shrink properties.
it preferred size of the element in a flex container, but can be overridden by the flex-grow if there is extra space or a need to shrink.
it use like that
.container {display: flex;}



 .other-container{flex-basis: 200px; flex-grow:1; flex-shrink:1;}

